# How to make running Python 3 Script in Sublime Text responsive?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tic-tac-toe, build-system

I am new to Python.

I have been creating my first personal project, `a tic tac toe game`.

I wrote it in Sublime Text and tried running it in the macOS terminal. It works beautifully. However, when I try running it in Sublime Text itself while the first part shows it does not respond to my input of cell number in the Tic Tac Toe game.

`https://i.imgur.com/NM6h1CT.png`.

Please help me create a build system or something that fixes this problem.
My current build system is

```
`{
 "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the 3rd-party [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) package for a Python REPL environment that enables interaction. Install by Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Control > Install Package, then type in and choose SublimeREPL. To run a piece of code, click on Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python.

Sublime Text itself doesn't accept any input.